# Create bar chart with buckets NOT using count in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

For some reason this is completely eluding me. I am trying to create a bar chart in R where the x values are buckets of one variable (e.g. 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc) and the y value is the median value for another variable within that bucketed range.

So, if my values were:

```
x   y
2   5
4   6
6   6
10  7
14  15
17  18
```

I would want to make a chart graphing the median y by x, with two buckets for x values, one from 1-10 and one from 11-20. The height of the bar for 1-10 would be the median value of y for that range of x, or 6 in this case. The height of the bar for 11-20 would be the median value of y for that range, or 16.5 in this case.

I don't know how to do this, except by "hard-coding" it in and adding a new column via an if statement which checks the x value and adds a new string in the column saying something like "1-10", but this strikes me as a terrible solution.

I've looked at other Stack Exchange answers, but they are almost always dealing with counts, not the median of another value.

Would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one way to go. I'd probably use `cut()` and create a new group variable. Then, summarise the data in order to get median for each group. Here, I called your data `mydf`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

group_by(mydf, group = cut(x, breaks = c(1, 10, 20), labels = c("1-10", "11-20"))) %>%
summarise(median = median(y)) -> mydf2

ggplot(data = mydf2, aes(x = group, y = median)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]